# Update Status when each order time past 20 minutes

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, lumen, jenssegers-mongodb

I use Laravel Lumen framework and jenssegers/laravel-mongodb package , my query in project is :

```
    $time_5_min_ago = Carbon::now()->subMinute(5);
    $time_10_min_ago = Carbon::now()->subMinute(10);
    $time_15_min_ago = Carbon::now()->subMinute(15);
    $time_20_min_ago = Carbon::now()->subMinute(20);



    return Order::where(function ($query)  use ($maxLat_try_one,$minLat_try_one,$maxLon_try_one,$minLon_try_one,$time_5_min_ago,$time_10_min_ago) {
        $query->whereBetween('source_longitude', [$minLon_try_one, $maxLon_try_one])
            ->whereBetween('source_latitude', [$minLat_try_one,$maxLat_try_one])
            ->where('status', '=', 'pending')
            ->where('created_at', '<', $time_5_min_ago)
            ->where('created_at', '>=', $time_10_min_ago);
    })->orWhere(function ($query)  use ($maxLat_try_two,$minLat_try_two,$maxLon_try_two,$minLon_try_two,$time_10_min_ago,$time_15_min_ago) {
        $query->whereBetween('source_longitude', [$minLon_try_two, $maxLon_try_two])
            ->whereBetween('source_latitude', [$minLat_try_two,$maxLat_try_two])
            ->where('status', '=', 'pending')
            ->where('created_at', '<', $time_10_min_ago)
            ->where('created_at', '>=', $time_15_min_ago);
    })->orWhere(function ($query)  use ($maxLat_try_three,$minLat_try_three,$maxLon_try_three,$minLon_try_three,$time_15_min_ago,$time_20_min_ago) {
        $query->whereBetween('source_longitude', [$minLon_try_three, $maxLon_try_three])
            ->whereBetween('source_latitude', [$minLat_try_three,$maxLat_try_three])
            ->where('status', '=', 'pending')
            ->where('created_at', '<', $time_15_min_ago)
            ->where('created_at', '>=', $time_20_min_ago);
    })->get($fields);
```

I want to any order exist in top query and in last `orWehere` query , order created_at was < 20 minutes ago and status still was pending that order status updated to suspend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **Laravel's Commands** combined with **schedule** and you will get what you want.

Here's a detailed explanation:

### Step 1: Create a command called "ChangePendingToSuspended"

Open a console then execute

```
php artisan make:console ChangePendingToSuspended
```

### Step 2: Open up `ChangePendingToSuspended.php`

you can find it in your `app/Console/Commands/` directory and tamper with it's parameters like adding a **description**

```
protected $description = 'Changes the Requests which has been in pending status for a period of time to suspended status.';
```

and a **signature**

```
protected $signature = 'requests:clear-pending';
```

Ok, before you ask "What's a signature?"
A signature is a way of executing the command from the console for example now you can manually initiate the `ChangePendingToSuspended` command from artisan like

```
php artisan requests:clear-pending
```

### Step 3: Defining our command

Now you put your code into the `handle` method in your case it might be something in the context of:

```
public function handle(){
    \DB::table('requests')
        ->where('created_at','<',\Carbon\Carbon::now()->addMinutes(-20))
        ->update(['status'=>'suspended']);
}
```

Just use whatever method that you prefer to change the status in that command.

### Step 4: Adding the command to the Schedule

Open up `Kernel.php` found in `app\Console\` directory
you will be presented with an array called $commands, add our class to it

```
 protected $commands = [
        Commands\Inspire::class,
        Commands\ChangePendingToSuspended::class,
    ];
```

Now go to the schedule method and schedule your newly created command

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
...
        $schedule->command('requests:change-pending-to-investigate')->everyFiveMinutes();
...
    }
```

Ok what's happening here is that now, every five minutes, the scheduler will execute our command `ChangePendingToSuspended` each five minutes,
but there's still 1 more step, we need to make the schedule tick by adding it's cron job to our system.

### Step 5: add the schedule cron entry to your server

this differs among servers and releases, whether you are using windows, or linux or osx

but here's the cron entry

for linux:

```
* * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

for windows (using the task scheduler):

```
* * * * path/to/php path/to/artisan schedule:run 1>> NUL 2>&1
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use Eloquen attribute instead of update database every minute.

```
public function getStatusAttribute() {
 if($this->created > ....) {
   $status = "pending";
 } else if(...) {
   ....
 }
 return $status;
}
```

Comment: Sorry you can add more detailed explanation of what that must do . Because I didn't do this thing ever